# Lost dynamically added click events to each TableCell in each TableRow

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, data-binding, webforms

I'm developing live-table with `WebForms`.

I'm adding such control to each TableCell in each TableRow, when I'm adding new rows to the table:

```
// in some method, which creates the table

TableRow row = new TableRow();

// here goes other cells with text data

TableCell cellActions = new TableCell();
cellActions.ID = "offerActionsOfferId" + enumerator.Current.offerId;

// init button View More for cell
LinkButton buttonViewExpanded = new LinkButton();
buttonViewExpanded.ID = "buttonViewExpandedOfferId" + enumerator.Current.offerId;
buttonViewExpanded.CssClass = "table-actions-button ic-table-edit";
buttonViewExpanded.Click += new EventHandler(buttonViewExpanded_Click);
buttonViewExpanded.ToolTip = "some alt...";
cellActions.Controls.Add(buttonViewExpanded);
/* end of Action Buttons */

...

row.Cells.Add(cellActions);
this.tableMarket.Controls.Add(row);
```

But there is a fail with the `new EventHandler(buttonViewExpanded_Click)` method.

Table renders in the ASPX page pretty well and all controls are visible, but a fail occurs when I try to click that LinkButton.

When I've marked a breakpoint and try to catch the execution of my ASP.NET program in the debugger to make some analyse of program work - the page only refreshed and no one breakpoint in the click event handler has been caught.

Why does it occur? And how to make it work?

Comment: Where did you render above code? For example, `Page_Load`, `Page_Init`. Please upload the rest of your code which is important to determine the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test your code; it ties to other classes like `InternalApi`. However, here is what I found.

You need to figure out the way to load **SetTableBodyForSceneMarket** in **page init**.

It basically reload dynamically created controls on post back; otherwise, those controls will be null, and cannot fire events.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    if(IsPostBack)
    {
        SetTableBodyForSceneMarket();
    }
}

private void SetTableBodyForSceneMarket()
{
  ...
}
```