# Button Event Handler Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following lines of code for a `button` in `C#` :

```
void reserve_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string req = ((Button)sender).ID;
}

 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            issuedBooks.Visible = false;
            search.Visible = true;
            string text = TextBox1.Text;
            string selectCommand = "SELECT id, title, author FROM book WHERE title LIKE '%" + text + "%' OR author LIKE '%" + text + "%'";
            string conString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlDataAdapter dad = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, conString);
            DataTable dtblCategories = new DataTable();
            dad.Fill(dtblCategories);
            DataView view = new DataView(dtblCategories);



            foreach (DataRowView row in view)
            {
                TableRow newrow = new TableRow();
                TableCell newcell1 = new TableCell();
                TableCell newcell2 = new TableCell();
                TableCell newcell3 = new TableCell();    
                newcell1.Text = row["title"].ToString();
                newrow.Cells.Add(newcell1);
                newcell2.Text = row["author"].ToString();
                newrow.Cells.Add(newcell2);

                string book_id = row["id"].ToString();

                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.ID = "Button_1" + book_id;
                btn.Text = "Reserve";
                btn.Click += new EventHandler(reserve_click);

                newcell3.Controls.Add(btn);
                newrow.Cells.Add(newcell3);

                search.Rows.Add(newrow);

             }
```

I am using the above code in a dynamically added button in a table cell. But the above `EventHandler` is not working or getting fired. I am using `asp.net` and `C#`for the first time. Can someone help me out ? Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us the code of `reserve_click` and where you add it to the form?

Comment: check the question again

Comment: "But the above EventHandler is not working or getting fired." - What *is* happening?

Comment: I added a breakpoint. It was unable to reach there. On clicking the button.. the `EventHandler` was not working.

Comment: most of strange cases like this one are caused by a very hidden mistake from the OPs, they make the others confused in a very innocent way.

Comment: It obviously looks alright. Without access to more info, these would be my main suspicions for a start: **1.** The button you're clicking is not the button you attached the event handler to. **2.** The event handler gets disattached by some code you have not posted but which gets executed in meantime. **3.** Since the event handler does nothing with your req variable, perhaps its body got optimized away and that's why you never hit the breakpoint? Make the event handler do something visible.

Comment: @kamalbhai: where are you creating this button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652642/lost-dynamically-added-click-events-to-each-tablecell-in-each-tablerow

Answer (score -1):

here is the answer.Try it

```
Page_Load()
{
   Button b = new Button();
   b.ID = topic.Topic_Id + "_1"; // topic_Id is my unique ID for each topic on the blog
   b.Text = "Edit";
   b.ToolTip = "Edit";
   b.CommandArgument = b.ID; //passing this to event handler
   b.Command += new CommandEventHandler(b_Command); //handler
}
void b_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

Comment: you are adding this to page_load event but mine is implemented in another button click event handler .